# how to connect to Cassandra with Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have included [cqerl](https://github.com/matehat/cqerl) in my project the Erlang driver for Elixir
According to the documentation the Erlang syntax to connect is:

```
{ok, Client} = cqerl:new_client({}).
```

I just do not know how to translate the above to Elixir syntax.

Comment: Did you connect to server using credentials, ip and port? Can you share your connection code? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using Erlang via Elixir you have to call the Erlang module like this:

```
{:ok, client} = :cqerl.new_client({})
```

If you want to invoke Cassandra using a specific address you can create a new client as described in the [cqerl documentation:](https://github.com/matehat/cqerl#all-modes)

```
{:ok, client} = :cqerl.new_client({"127.0.0.1", 9042})
```

or if you indend to pass in more options such as authentification as second parameter (It is usually a bad idea to put your password in the code, rather use env variables or a config file ignored by git):

```
{:ok, client} = :cqerl.new_client({"127.0.0.1", 9042}, , [{auth, {cqerl_auth_plain_handler, [{"Your-Username", "Your-Password"}]}}])
```

Comment: It says `invalid arguments for use, expected an atom or alias as argument`

Comment: This is an exact translation of the code you provided. If this is broken, so is the example in your question.

Comment: I have serious doubts about passing ```{}``` as an argument. This is quite meaningless. It is, however, the first example in the cqerl readme.

Comment: It's not meaningless, it's using erlang's pattern matching to invoke `new_client({}) ->` in the cqerl module.

Comment: How would ip, port, credentials like username and password get inserted in the new_client command above?